# What does font-size 62.5% do?

Tags: html, css

**What is 62.5% here! And what does it do** **              **

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}  

html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[Google](http://www.google.com/).

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking what a `%` in a `font-size` declaration does or are you looking for some assistance centering (vertically & horizontally) a div? If it's the last one, please provide your HTML also. If it's the first one, read here: [CSS Font-Size: em vs. px vs. pt vs. percent](https://kyleschaeffer.com/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs-percent)

Comment: your question is quite not clear.. you've applied 62.5% to a font. It has nothing to do with positioning a div horizontally or vertically.  If you can, edit your question to what exactly you want to achieve

Comment: I know about font sizing and percentages. But I'm curious about "font-size: 62.5%", I see this quite often in codes. Why set it to 62.5% not 70% or 80%. Thanks for help!

Comment: Can you you then revise/edit your answer to be more clear. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`font-size: 62.5%;` on `html` tag is a method helping you to convert easily `px` to `rem`.

As 62.5% of the default font size in browser (16px) is equal to 10px, convert pixel values to `rem` values become easy. For example, 1.6rem will have a 16px rendering (16/10=1.6).

You can get more informations about CSS font size units on this link : https://medium.com/code-better/css-units-for-font-size-px-em-rem-79f7e592bb97

Answer (score -2):

Percent in font size is used to make it scalable wrt different devices. i.e mobile, desktop ipad etc.